# HTML file creation

Tags: iphone, html, objective-c, ios, xcode

I try to create HTML file programaticatically. But generated file shown me as blank file. I don't know the issue.

Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction) createFileAction
{
    NSLog(@"************* createFileAction *************");
    NSMutableString *htmlString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"%@",htmlString);
    [htmlString appendString:@"<html><head><title></title><style type='text/css'>.style1{height: 27px;}#Text1{height: 19px;width: 210px;}.style2{width: 255px;}.style3{height: 27px;width: 255px;}#petValue{width: 206px;}#nameValue{width: 206px;}#dateValue{width: 209px;}"];
    [htmlString appendString:@"#Text2{width: 215px;}#Text3{width: 210px;height: 22px;}#Text4{width: 209px;}.style8{width: 13px;}.style9{ width: 263px;}.style10{height: 27px;width: 263px;}"];
    [htmlString appendString:@".style11{width: 418px;}.style12{width: 199px;}.style13{height: 27px; width: 199px;}.style14{height: 24px;}.style15{width: 410px;}</style> </head>"];
    [htmlString appendString:@"<body>"];

    NSString *originalString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.makepartsfast.com/2012/09/4337/more-3d-printing-in-metals-ex-one-introduces-the-m-flex-3d-printing-system/"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:originalString];
    NSString *extractedString = nil;


    [scanner scanUpToString:@"<div class=\"postarea\">" intoString:nil];
    [scanner scanString:@"<div class=\"postarea\">" intoString:nil];



    [scanner scanUpToString:@"<div style=\"clear:both;\">" intoString:&extractedString];


    if (extractedString) 
    {
        // string was extracted
        NSLog(@"%@", extractedString);
    }   
    NSLog(@"BEFORE= %@",htmlString);
    [htmlString appendString:extractedString];
     NSLog(@"AFTER= %@",htmlString);
    [htmlString appendString:@"</body></html>"];
    NSLog(@"FINAL=%@",htmlString);

    // check to see if file already exists in documents directory
    if([self.fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:self.file])
    {
        NSLog(@"File already exists");
    }
    else 
    {
        NSLog(@"file does not exist");
        NSLog(@"Try creating the file");

        // file does not already exist so create it
        [self.fileMgr createFileAtPath:file contents:nil attributes:nil];

        NSLog(@"%@",htmlString);
        [htmlString writeToFile:self.file atomically:NO encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy error:nil];


        //Test again whether this file exists now that we have tried creating it
        if([self.fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:self.file])
        {
            NSLog(@"File exists now");
        }
        else 
        {
            NSLog(@"File still doesn't exist");
        }

    }
}
```

In this method, I get only select portion from the URL in **extractedString** in html format & append it to htmlstring. when i try to append different string then it works fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you passed `NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy` as the `encoding` argument. You should be passing one of the string encoding arguments. What's happening is that `NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy` is equal to 1. But `writeToFile:atomically:encoding:error:` is expecting a string encoding constant. The string encoding constant equal to 1 is `NSASCIIStringEncoding`. But your string can't be converted to ASCII, so you get an empty file. Change that line to use UTF8 and you get the expected non-empty file:

```
[htmlString writeToFile:self.file atomically:NO encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

You had trouble with this at least partly because **you are not checking return types or error conditions**. The method call returns `BOOL` and will create an `NSError` if anything goes wrong. This would have helped you figure out what was wrong, if you were listening. If you had done this:

```
NSError *saveError = nil;
if (![htmlString writeToFile:file atomically:NO encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy error:&saveError]) {
    NSLog(@"Error writing file: %@", saveError);
}
```

You would have seen an error message reading something like:

```
2012-11-21 11:20:47.250 Untitled[5731:707] Error writing file: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=517 "The file “junk.html” couldn’t be saved using text encoding Western (ASCII)." UserInfo=0x7ffc0860b7c0 {NSFilePath=/tmp/junk.html, NSStringEncoding=1
```

That might not be obvious *at first* but the fact that it specifically mentions trying to use ASCII would have been a huge clue to the source of the problem.